# What are the linux signals that can be trapped in Tcl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcl, signals

I am working on a `Tcl` project where a certain procedure will run continuously. user can abort that procedure anytime using some Key-Combination. So basically, I need to `trap` the signal within `Tcl` code. So far, everything is done except one problem.

I am using `Ctrl+Z` i.e. `SIGSUSP` signal (`SIGTSTP` in case of Tcl) which technically does the job.

```
signal trap sigtstp onAbort
```

But, pressing `Ctrl+Z` immediately returns the Shell prompt, rest of the output from the program comes after that and when output comes to an end, no shell prompt returned (as it is already returned before). I need to press `Enter` again to get the prompt.

Following is the case I am refering to. You can see the prompt (`polaris@ubuntu:~$`) is returned in between output of the main program.

[image]

Also as output of pressing `Ctrl+Z`, it returned `[40]+ Stopped`, which is bit annoying. Can I avoid this ?

Can I avoid this whole problem using some other key-combination i.e. signal ? Or can I avoid this with `Ctrl+Z` also by tweking something ?

NOTE: I have tried using `Ctrl+C`. I got the exactly expected behavior with that. Unfortunately I can't use `Ctrl+C` as it is used for some other functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> causes the shell to send the current foreground process a `SIGSTOP`(19).  This signal cannot be caught or ignored and so your program will receive it and run the default handler. This is not killing the process as your question suggests you're trying to do. This only suspends it and you can bring it back into the foreground using [`fg` on most modern shells](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html).

Looks like you're out of luck. However, you might be able to rebind the keychord at the level of the shell. This is outside your program though and your end users don't have control over it. (Cf. https://superuser.com/questions/378018/how-can-i-do-ctrl-z-and-bg-in-one-keypress-to-make-process-continue-in-backgroun)

Also, if your program relies on user inputs for various actions (since you suggest that C-c does something else), perhaps you should make it a full fledged CUI application using curses or something?

Comment: Actually, `Ctrl`+`z` sends a SIGTSTP, which _can_ be intercepted. It's still very highly advised to stop the process when that is sent, but some cleanup (e.g., of the terminal) can be done on the way.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that.